# Google chrome "Sources" tab has only css files

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, vpn

I am using React in my project. I used to debug with breakpoints directly in the Google chrome Sources tab (by searching the file with cmd + P and adding breakpoints).
Now the problem is when I search my file with cmd + P, the JSX file is not visible. Only the CSS files are shown here.

It was working all good a few days ago.[image: SS]
Please help.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No, but there are two workarounds. 
1. Restart the app
2. Use firefox

Comment: I am seeing this same problem. What was the solution?

Comment: For me I just had to open up the dev tools, right click on the refresh button and choose empty cache and hard reload. Also try a new tab or incognito mode.